# Fishing ethernet lines in attic for cameras

Tags: wiring, ethernet, cable-management

I am looking for advice on how to fish two ethernet cables through Hardie board into the attic. The space where I am trying to fish the cables is a vaulted ceiling.

I have never fished cables so this is new to me and I am not sure the best way to go about this. Any helpful recommendations on how to do this would be most appreciated.

[image]

Here are the spots I would like to install two PoE cameras

[image]

picture of roof

[image]

inside picture (don't mind the plastic tarp, I am doing some painting)

[image]

Comment: Painting is good, because then you are ready to paint after you rip drywall and run cables, and repair drywall, after fishing fails. I'd run outside-rated cables along the trim boards until you reach a more reasonable point to enter the building. I speak as someone who's current "day job" is primarily running cables. I make every effort to avoid obnoxious runs like that, they are miserable and prone to unpleasant interactions with the unknown.

Comment: Thanks @Ecnerwal, appreciate the advice. Definitely don't want to tear out drywall, hardie board, or anything else. Where do you think would be a good entry? here? https://i.imgur.com/saaqHb4l.png. Would you leave the cable exposed? and what would you use to secure the ethernet cable to the hardie plank?

Comment: It looks like the bottom of the fascia boards are lower than the soffit, leaving a lip where you could attach cat6 to the backside of the fascia? Does following that up and to the right get you away from the vaulted ceiling, where you could enter a more accessible spot in the attic? (And even if there is no lip, it might be less work to fish through the soffit than above an insulated vaulted ceiling.)

Comment: Yes, you are correct, front piece is lower and would hide the cable. Would you leave the cable exposed or run some type of conduit? Here is a better picture of the right side, would you try to enter next to the lip where the white circle is. https://i.imgur.com/wzHVYKth.jpg

Comment: **Outside/exterior rated cable** Exposed, Standard cable clips and screws (as seen on a billion cable TV runs, for instance) or screw-eye cable ties (but the clips are neater for this application.) Conduit is not needed in this location (out of reach) with the right cable, and won't help with the wrong cable, so skip conduit.

Comment: Are you referring to CMR cable? https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=13677. It won't be exposed to sun or water. I would tuck it behind the overhang so you won't even be able to see it (hopefully). As for the clips, I can't find anything I can use for hardie plank.

Comment: It's outside the building envelope. It is, by definition, exposed to water. So riser cable is NOT what I mean. I mean cable actually rated for outdoor use, which does not care about sun, or water, and won't stop working when you find that water gets the darndest places and interior-rated cables **do not like it.** It would also be surprising if the entirety of the run was protected from sun, but it just does not matter. Exterior rated cable is available, inexpensive, and the right stuff for the job.

Comment: Got it. Looks like Shireen makes an outdoor CAT6. https://www.shireeninc.com/osc/dc-2030-outdoor-cat6-with-dry-gel-tape-utp-by-ft